# Azure kubernetes service node pool upgrades & patches

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have some confusion on AKS Node pool upgrades and Patching. Could you please clarify on this.

1. I have one AKS node pool, which is having 4 nodes, so now I want to upgrade the kubernetes version only in two nodes of node pool. Is it possible?

   if it is possible to upgrade in two nodes, then how we can upgrade remaining two nodes? and how we can find out which two nodes are having old kubernetes version instead of latest kubernetes version
2. While doing the Upgrade process, will it create two new nodes with latest kubernetes version, and then will it delete old nodes in node pool?
3. Actually azure automatically applies patches on nodes, but will it creates new nodes with new patches and deleted old nodes?

Comment: Why would you like to update only 2 nodes?

Comment: @Amit: When we upgrade in all nodes. It will effect to applications which are running. it is just my assumption only

Comment: @Amit. Suppose if I do upgrade in all nodes. will it create new nodes with latest kubernetes version and deleted old nodes?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/upgrade-cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1**. According to the docs:

- you can [upgrade specific node pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-image-upgrade#upgrade-a-specific-node-pool).

So the approach with additional node-pool mentioned by [4c74356b41](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63501711/11207414).

---

- Additional info:

> [**Node upgrades**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-updates-kured#node-upgrades)

There is an additional process in AKS that lets you upgrade a cluster. **An upgrade is typically to move to a newer version of Kubernetes, not just apply node security updates**.
An AKS upgrade performs the following actions:

- A new node is deployed with the latest security updates and Kubernetes version applied.
- An old node is cordoned and drained.
- Pods are scheduled on the new node.
- The old node is deleted.

**2**. By default, AKS uses one additional node to configure upgrades.

You can control this process by increase [--max-surge parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-image-upgrade#upgrade-node-images-with-node-surge)

> To speed up the node image upgrade process, you can upgrade your node images using a customizable node surge value.

**3**. [Security and kernel updates to Linux nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-updates-kured):

> In an AKS cluster, your **Kubernetes nodes run as Azure virtual machines (VMs)**. These Linux-based VMs use an Ubuntu image, **with the OS configured** to automatically **check for updates every night**. **If security or kernel updates are available, they are automatically downloaded and installed**.

> **Some security updates**, such as kernel updates, **require a node reboot** to finalize the process. A Linux node that requires a reboot creates a file named /var/run/reboot-required. **This reboot process doesn't happen automatically**.

---

- [This tutorial summarize the process of Cluster Maintenance and Other Tasks](https://www.stackrox.com/post/2020/03/azure-kubernetes-aks-security-best-practices-part-4-of-4/)

Comment: there is no second approach. I mentioned you can speed up the upgrade but its still the same process

Answer (score 1):

1. no, create another pool with 2 nodes and test your application there. or create another cluster. you can find node version with `kubectl get nodes`
2. it gradually updates nodes one by one (default). you can change these. spot instances cannot be upgraded.
3. yes, latest patch version image will be used

Comment: 1. My doubt is.If I have four nodes in one node pool, and trying to upgrade kubernetes version in all nodes, in this case will it create another four nodes with latest kubernetes versions and deleted the old nodes or will it upgrade the kubernetes version with existing nodes                                                                                                                       2. while doing patching on nodes in node pool, will it create new nodes with new patch version and deleted the old nodes or just apply patch on existing nodes?

Comment: it never patches anything. it always recreates node from scratch